# What is this CONTEXT in Go lang when talking about HTTP Requests?

Tags: http, go

To some this might be a stupid question. On the other hand this is is very important to me. I am new to Go programming and when I read this [Sharing values between Middlewares](https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/share-values-between-middlewares-context-golang/) and this [Go Concurrency Patterns: Context](http://blog.golang.org/context) I could not figure out what exactly what they meant by Context when referring to sharing values between middleware handlers or request handlers in general.

I've been able to write a web framework with Go -- [Frodo](https://github.com/kn9ts/frodo). Not perfect in a lot of ways, it was a learning experiment. As you see I am not stupid. Just under informed being new to Go lang.

Thank you in advance for a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: https://joeshaw.org/net-context-and-http-handler/ is a good explanation. A *request* context is just that: storage local to that request, and that is dropped once that request completes. You would typically authenticate a user and then store their userID in the context, or their preferred language, or a CSRF token, etc.

Comment: @elithrar Thanks for the short explanation. Let see if the article you've shared makes the cut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a great explanation at the beginning of this blog: [HTTP Request Contexts & Go](http://elithrar.github.io/article/map-string-interface/)

> Request contexts, for those new to the terminology, are typically a
>   way to pass data alongside a HTTP request as it is processed by
>   handlers (or middleware) you have written. 
>   This data could be a user ID, a CSRF token, a web token, 
>   whether a user is logged in or not—something typically
>   derived from logic that you don't want to repeat over-and-over again
>   in every handler. If you've ever used Django, the request context is
>   synonymous with the request.META dictionary.